# PHP SMTP Script "Failed to Initiate Authentication" error

Tags: php, html, sendmail

I've been searching for a solution however even after reviewing several similar threads I haven't been able to find one that works for my situation.

I run it through a test script and get this output:

```
string(33) "Failed to Initiate Authentication"
```

I can't figure out what is causing the error, event after several attempts at troubleshooting the problem.

This is my code:

```
<?php

$SMTP_SERVER = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';
$SMTP_PORT = 25;
$SMTP_USERNAME = 'no-reply@website.com';
$SMTP_PASSWORD = 'password';
$SMTP_FROM = 'no-reply@website.com';


function smtpmail($to, $subject, $message, $headers = ''){


// set as global variable
global $SMTP_SERVER, $SMTP_PORT, $SMTP_USERNAME, $SMTP_PASSWORD, $SMTP_FROM;


// get From address
if ( $headers && preg_match("/From:.*?[A-Za-z0-9\._%-]+\@[A-Za-z0-9\._%-]+.*/", $headers, $froms) ){
    preg_match("/[A-Za-z0-9\._%-]+\@[A-Za-z0-9\._%-]+/", $froms[0], $fromarr);
    $from = $fromarr[0];
}else{
    $from = $SMTP_FROM;
    $headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n".$headers;
    }

// Clean some of this stuff up...

// escape the message
$message = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $message);

// also escape any leading period
if($message[0] == '.'){
    $message = '.'. $message;
    }

// escape the subject
$subject = str_replace( array("\r", "\n"), '', $subject );

// escape the recipient
$to = str_replace( array("\r", "\n"), '', $to );

// making sure not to send a zero, 'null', or etc.     ambiguity ftw..</sarcasm>
if(!$headers) $headers = '';



// Open an SMTP connection
$cp = fsockopen ($SMTP_SERVER, $SMTP_PORT, &$errno, &$errstr, 1);
if (!$cp)
return "Failed to even make a connection";
$res=fgets($cp,256);
if(substr($res,0,3) != "220") return "Failed to connect";

// Say hello...
fputs($cp, "HELO ".$SMTP_SERVER."\r\n");
$res=fgets($cp,256);
if(substr($res,0,3) != "250") return "Failed to Introduce";

// perform authentication
fputs($cp, "auth login\r\n");
$res=fgets($cp,256);
if(substr($res,0,3) != "334") return "Failed to Initiate Authentication";

fputs($cp, base64_encode($SMTP_USERNAME)."\r\n");
$res=fgets($cp,256);
if(substr($res,0,3) != "334") return "Failed to Provide Username for Authentication";

fputs($cp, base64_encode($SMTP_PASSWORD)."\r\n");
$res=fgets($cp,256);
if(substr($res,0,3) != "235") return "Failed to Authenticate";

// Mail from...
fputs($cp, "MAIL FROM: <$from>\r\n");
$res=fgets($cp,256);
if(substr($res,0,3) != "250") return "MAIL FROM failed";

// Rcpt to...
fputs($cp, "RCPT TO: <$to>\r\n");
$res=fgets($cp,256);
if(substr($res,0,3) != "250") return "RCPT TO failed";

// Data...
fputs($cp, "DATA\r\n");
$res=fgets($cp,256);
if(substr($res,0,3) != "354") return "DATA failed";


// Send To:, Subject:, other headers, blank line, message, and finish
// with a period on its own line (for end of message)
fputs($cp, "To: $to\r\nSubject: $subject\r\n$headers\r\n$message\r\n.\r\n");
$res=fgets($cp,256);
if(substr($res,0,3) != "250") return "Message Body Failed";

// ...And time to quit...
fputs($cp,"QUIT\r\n");
$res=fgets($cp,256);
if(substr($res,0,3) != "221") return "QUIT failed";

return true;
}

//var_dump(smtpmail('mramonster@hotmail.com', 'email subject', ".\r\njust a: (message) 'that'\nwill <a href='http://www.google.com/'>hopefully</a> %get #through\r\n.\r\nsomething","From: test@example.com\r\n"));

?>
```

I've already double checked the User Name, Server, Password, E-mail, etc. I still can't figure out what the error might be.

Note: I don't use "no-reply@website.com" or "password" as my credentials.

Comment: Not at the moment, but if it's easier that way then I can use g-mail.

Comment: Why not use a package like swiftmailer instead?  Otherwise, output the `$res` instead of 'Failed to Initiate Authentication'.

Comment: I'm looking at Swiftmailer now.

Also:
string(26) "500 command unrecognized " I'm not really sure how to print the $res I just inserted it where 'failed to initiate was'

Comment: Looks like you are sending a misc command the STMP server doesn't recognize.  Try this `"AUTH=LOGIN\r\n"` instead of "auth login\r\n" and see if that does anything different.

Comment: It now looks like this 'fputs($cp, "AUTH=LOGIN\r\n");' however it still outputs with '500 command unrecognized'.

Comment: dunno... try another package, or swiftmailer and see if that helps.

Comment: I'll try and use Swiftmailer, I never understand how to install those Auto Mailers though.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't we use PEAR's Mail package which make life easy !

Download Url: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected

PEAR's Mail package defines an interface for implementing mailers under the PEAR hierarchy. It also provides supporting functions useful to multiple mailer backends. Currently supported backends include: PHP's native mail() function, sendmail, and **SMTP**.

Here is a code example:

```
<?php

//Include the Pear Mail package
include("Mail.php");

/* mail setup recipients, subject etc */
$recipients = "feedback@yourdot.com";
$headers["From"] = "user@somewhere.com";
$headers["To"] = "feedback@yourdot.com";
$headers["Subject"] = "User feedback";
$mailmsg = "Hello, This is a test.";

/* SMTP server name, port, user/passwd */
$smtpinfo["host"] = "smtp.mycorp.com";
$smtpinfo["port"] = "25";
$smtpinfo["auth"] = true;
$smtpinfo["username"] = "smtpusername";
$smtpinfo["password"] = "smtpPassword";

/* Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method */
$mail_object =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);

/* Ok send mail */
$mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $mailmsg);

?>
```